# Unable to start a multipass instance: Failed start validation for device "eth0": Instance DNS name "currentlts" already used on network

Tags: 22.04, lxd, multipass

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop (x86_64) and on it I have seven Ubuntu 22.04 instances. They have all been running fine; six still are.

However, one of them does not start any more. When I issue:

```
multipass start CurrentLTS
//OR multipass shell CurrentLTS
```

I immediately get the following error:

```
[2022-12-22T10:48:40.491] [error] [lxd request] Operation completed with error: (400) Failed start validation for device "eth0": Instance DNS name "currentlts" already used on network
start failed: Operation completed with error: (400) Failed start validation for device "eth0": Instance DNS name "currentlts" already used on network
```

There is no instance named `currentlts` or any with a name close to it. Here is the `multipass info CurrentLTS` output:

```
Name:           CurrentLTS
State:          Stopped
IPv4:           --
Release:        --
Image hash:     6159291f6783 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
Load:           --
Disk usage:     --
Memory usage:   --
Mounts:         --
```

If I run the `start` command with `-vvvv` I get the following output:

```
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.970] [trace] [lxd request] Requesting LXD: GET unix://multipass/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket@1.0/virtual-machines/CurrentLTS/state?project=multipass
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.973] [trace] [lxd request] Got reply: {                    
"error": "",
"error_code": 0,
"metadata": {
    "cpu": {
        "usage": 0
    },
    "disk": null,
    "memory": {
        "swap_usage": 0,
        "swap_usage_peak": 0,
        "usage": 0,
        "usage_peak": 0
    },
    "network": null,
    "pid": 0,
    "processes": 0,
    "status": "Stopped",
    "status_code": 102
},
"operation": "",
"status": "Success",
"status_code": 200,
"type": "sync"
}

[2022-12-22T11:05:42.973] [trace] [CurrentLTS] Got LXD container state: CurrentLTS is Stopped
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.973] [trace] [lxd request] Requesting LXD: GET unix://multipass/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket@1.0/virtual-machines/CurrentLTS/state?project=multipass
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.975] [trace] [lxd request] Got reply: {                    
"error": "",
"error_code": 0,
"metadata": {
    "cpu": {
        "usage": 0
    },
    "disk": null,
    "memory": {
        "swap_usage": 0,
        "swap_usage_peak": 0,
        "usage": 0,
        "usage_peak": 0
    },
    "network": null,
    "pid": 0,
    "processes": 0,
    "status": "Stopped",
    "status_code": 102
},
"operation": "",
"status": "Success",
"status_code": 200,
"type": "sync"
}

[2022-12-22T11:05:42.975] [trace] [CurrentLTS] Got LXD container state: CurrentLTS is Stopped
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.975] [trace] [lxd request] Requesting LXD: GET unix://multipass/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket@1.0/virtual-machines/CurrentLTS/state?project=multipass
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.978] [trace] [lxd request] Got reply: {                    
"error": "",
"error_code": 0,
"metadata": {
    "cpu": {
        "usage": 0
    },
    "disk": null,
    "memory": {
        "swap_usage": 0,
        "swap_usage_peak": 0,
        "usage": 0,
        "usage_peak": 0
    },
    "network": null,
    "pid": 0,
    "processes": 0,
    "status": "Stopped",
    "status_code": 102
},
"operation": "",
"status": "Success",
"status_code": 200,
"type": "sync"
}

[2022-12-22T11:05:42.978] [trace] [CurrentLTS] Got LXD container state: CurrentLTS is Stopped
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.978] [trace] [lxd request] Requesting LXD: PUT unix://multipass/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket@1.0/virtual-machines/CurrentLTS/state?project=multipass
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.978] [trace] [lxd request] Sending data: {"action":"start"}
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.985] [trace] [lxd request] Got reply: {                    
"error": "",
"error_code": 0,
"metadata": {
    "class": "task",
    "created_at": "2022-12-22T11:05:42.98045405-05:00",
    "description": "Starting instance",
    "err": "",
    "id": "5edff0b7-c80c-4949-9c2a-3c8c4fe13d79",
    "location": "none",
    "may_cancel": false,
    "metadata": null,
    "resources": {
        "instances": [
            "/1.0/instances/CurrentLTS"
        ]
    },
    "status": "Running",
    "status_code": 103,
    "updated_at": "2022-12-22T11:05:42.98045405-05:00"
},
"operation": "/1.0/operations/5edff0b7-c80c-4949-9c2a-3c8c4fe13d79",
"status": "Operation created",
"status_code": 100,
"type": "async"
}

[2022-12-22T11:05:42.985] [trace] [lxd request] Requesting LXD: GET unix://multipass/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket@1.0/operations/5edff0b7-c80c-4949-9c2a-3c8c4fe13d79/wait?project=multipass
[2022-12-22T11:05:42.989] [trace] [lxd request] Got reply: {                    
"error": "",
"error_code": 0,
"metadata": {
    "class": "task",
    "created_at": "2022-12-22T11:05:42.98045405-05:00",
    "description": "Starting instance",
    "err": "Failed start validation for device \"eth0\": Instance DNS name \"currentlts\" already used on network",
    "id": "5edff0b7-c80c-4949-9c2a-3c8c4fe13d79",
    "location": "none",
    "may_cancel": false,
    "metadata": null,
    "resources": {
        "instances": [
            "/1.0/instances/CurrentLTS"
        ]
    },
    "status": "Failure",
    "status_code": 400,
    "updated_at": "2022-12-22T11:05:42.98045405-05:00"
},
"operation": "",
"status": "Success",
"status_code": 200,
"type": "sync"
}

[2022-12-22T11:05:42.990] [error] [lxd request] Operation completed with error: (400) Failed start validation for device "eth0": Instance DNS name "currentlts" already used on network
start failed: Operation completed with error: (400) Failed start validation for device "eth0": Instance DNS name "currentlts" already used on network`
```

What might be causing this? This instance is the oldest instance of all the seven and has some critical apps on it.  I have run out of options.

If there's no way to start it, is there a way to recover the data from it?

```
Ubuntu 22.04 is running latest updates
multipass version 1.10.1
multipassd version 1.10.1
lxd version: 5.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to stumble upon the instance image which I copied and wrote onto an external drive. I was able to access all the app files I thought I had lost.

Here is how I located the image. I attempted to run `lxd recover` event though I knew it was not the right command, which displayed the following before I exited the command:

```
# lxd recover
This LXD server currently has the following storage pools:
- multipass (backend="dir", source="/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/multipass")
Would you like to recover another storage pool? (yes/no) [default=no]:
```

Then I looked into the storage pool:

```
# ls /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/multipass
buckets  containers  containers-snapshots  custom  custom-snapshots  images  virtual-machines  virtual-machines-snapshots
```

Then:

```
# ls /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/multipass/virtual-machines/multipass_CurrentLTS
agent-client.crt  agent-client.key  agent.crt  agent.key  backup.yaml  config  config.iso  metadata.yaml  qemu.nvram  root.img  templates
```

I figured the instance image must be `root.img` so I copied the file, 118GB, and used Archive Manager to write it to an external hard drive. Now I am able to access the files.

Does anyone know the best way to restore the instance? Or should I just delete the instance, install a new one with the required software and then copy the app files into it?